# Loop/JOIN results dynamically using UNION

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like following

```
| id | views                                                                     | actions                                                                   |
|----|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | {"group1":{"mobile":20,"desktop":36},"group2":{"mobile":25,"desktop":41}} | {"group1":{"mobile":4,"desktop":3},"group2":{"mobile":2,"desktop":4}}     |
| 2  | {"group1":{"mobile":40,"desktop":34},"group2":{"mobile":31,"desktop":45}} | {"group1":{"mobile":21,"desktop":19},"group2":{"mobile":23,"desktop":19}} |
| 3  | {"group1":{"mobile":53,"desktop":34},"group2":{"mobile":37,"desktop":75}} | {"group1":{"mobile":17,"desktop":14},"group2":{"mobile":30,"desktop":12}} |
```

And I want my results to look like following

```
| product     | views group 1  | views group 2  | actions group 1 | actions group 2 | actions per view group 1 | actions per view group 2 |
|-------------|----------------|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| 1 (mobile)  | 20             | 25             | 4               | 2               | (D2/B2) = 0.2            | (E2/C2) = 0.08           |
| 1 (desktop) | 36             | 41             | 3               | 4               | (D3/B3) = 0.115          | (E2/C2) = 0.09           |
| 2 (mobile)  | 40             | 31             | 21              | 23              | ...                      | ...                      |
| 2 (desktop) | 34             | 45             | 19              | 19              | ...                      | ...                      |
| 1 (overall) | (B2 + B3) = 56 | (C2 + C3) = 66 | ...             | ...             | ...                      | ...                      |
| 2 (overall) | (B4 + B5) = 84 | (C4 + C5) = 76 | ...             | ...             | ...                      | ...                      |
```

I can do it using the following SQL query, but I'm wondering if I can do it in a more cleaner or shorter way

```
SELECT
    CASE id WHEN 1 THEN '1 (mobile)' WHEN 2 THEN '2 (mobile)' END as product,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group1', 'mobile') AS actions_group_1,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group1', 'mobile') AS views_group_1,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group2', 'mobile') AS actions_group_2,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group2', 'mobile') AS views_group_2,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group1', 'mobile')/SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group1', 'mobile') AS actions_per_view_group_1 ,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group2', 'mobile')/SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group2', 'mobile') AS actions_per_view_group_2
FROM widget_daily_stats
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id

UNION

SELECT
    CASE id WHEN 1 THEN '1 (desktop)' WHEN 2 THEN '2 (desktop)' END as product,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group1', 'desktop') AS actions_group_1,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group1', 'desktop') AS views_group_1,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group2', 'desktop') AS actions_group_2,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group2', 'desktop') AS views_group_2,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group1', 'desktop')/SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group1', 'desktop') AS actions_per_view_group_1 ,
    SUM(json_extract_path_text(actions, 'group2', 'desktop')/SUM(json_extract_path_text(views, 'group2', 'desktop') AS actions_per_view_group_2
FROM widget_daily_stats
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id

UNION

...
```

There has to be a way for me to loop through mobile and desktop and dynamically UNION the results without having to explicitly UNION all the results

Comment: Okay np, I've removed the postgres tag

Answer (score 0):

The preferable solution is **not to store the data as JSON** inside Amazon Redshift. As you've seen, you need to use the `json_extract_path_text()` function to retrieve individual elements, which is quite slow.

Also, having fields stored in JSON means that Redshift cannot optimize storage and access. Redshift is *much* more efficient if the data is stored in separate fields (like you show in your output).

Therefore:

- Try to load the data directly into fields rather than as JSON objects (Use [COPY from JSON Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html))
- Or, load the JSON data into a staging table, then use a query like you have written above to extract the fields and then INSERT them into a new table. Then use that new table for all your queries. They'll run much more efficiently.

Sorry that this answer does not specifically address your UNION question, but you'll find that putting the data into a more usable format will help your ability to query it.

Comment: Well, I don't like that I have to use `json_extract_path_text` to extract my data either but I believe that is the right solution to the overall problem I'm trying to solve. I can have `n` number of groups for each column so I cannot have fixed number of columns to solve that

Comment: A common way of doing a 1-to-n relationship is to have a separate table that has one row per relationship. For example, one column each for `Group, Product, Count`. No JSON extraction required.